# What is the simplest way to copy a file from local to a shared folder by a PowerShell script?

Tags: .net, powershell, shared-directory

(I am asking this question as a developer without having not very deep system admin knowledge.)

I need to copy one file that I generate -which is a csv- to a Shared Folder in the network.

**What is the simplest, safest and warrantied way to achieve this within my PS Script**?

(Is it the same way to copy a file from one directory to another one -or there are things to be aware of in order to accomplish this without any problems?)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the same way to copy a file from one directory to another one

Yes.

`Copy-Item`

(or its `copy` alias).

> or there are things to be aware of in order to accomplish this without any problems?

Not particularly. Cross the network does introduce additional error cases (eg. network connectivity lost) but these are handled as failures of the `Copy-Item` (eg. destination could have insufficient space whether local or remote).

Comment: `Copy-Item c:\scripts c:\test -recurse`. Incidentally, the **-recurse** parameter is absolutely crucial here; leave it out and a Scripts folder will be created in C:\Test, but none of the files and folders in C:\Scripts will be copied to the new location; _you’ll create a C:\Test\Scripts folder, but there won’t be anything in it_.